# Pythonic way to handle if the file being written is deleted externally

Tags: python, python-3.x

A python process is writing to a file and the file has been deleted/moved by an external process (cron job in my case).

The python process will continue to execute without any errors (expected as it is being written to the buffer rather than the file and will be flushed after `f.close()`). Yet there won't be any new file created in this case and buffer will be silently discarded(**correct me if I'm wrong**).

Is there any pythonic way to handle this instead of checking if file exists and create one if not, before every write operation.

Comment: On \*NIX systems, it usually works the way that basically the system will remember that the file should be deleted as soon as all processes which have a handle on it relinquish said handle (simplified explanation). So, the file continues to exist until Python has finished writing to it, after which it will get removed. I'd rather ask why you need to handle the case that these two actions occur specifically, and perhaps that you need to avoid the deletion instead…?!

Comment: You could use [inotify](https://pypi.org/project/inotify/) to detect deletions, or even just check if the file exists before closing it. If it doesn't, you can write its contents to a newly created handle. Related question: [Why does writing to a file descriptor after the target file has been deleted succeed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8396436/why-does-writing-to-a-file-descriptor-after-the-target-file-has-been-deleted-suc)

Comment: @deceze in my streaming application I want to write the json data received to a flat-file locally and would like to remove this file based on size maybe(expected to behave as `RotatingFileHandler`, I'm not sure if I can use `RotatingFileHandler` for writing data)

Comment: Just checked that `RotatingFileHandler` can be used, with formatter as `formatter = logging.Formatter('%(message)s')`. Nonetheless, the question is generic enough that a solution can be used in other use cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no "pythonic" way to do this because the question isn't about a specific language. It's an operating system question. So the answer is going to be different for MS Windows than it is for a UNIX like OS such as Linux or macOS. To do this efficiently requires using a facility such as the Linux [inotify API](https://www.linuxjournal.com/content/linux-filesystem-events-inotify). A simpler approach that will work on any UNIX like OS is to open the file then call `os.fstat()` and remember the `st_ino` member of the returned object. Then periodically call `os.stat()` on the path name and compare its `st_ino` value to the one you saved earlier. If it changes, or the `os.stat()` call fails, then you know the file name you are writing to is no longer the same file.